# How to clear data from list before processing to next record

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have a List with let's say 3 records.I am processing the first record by using for loop and result gets generated.How to delete the first record before I process with other two records.Please find my code below:

```
public void processDataToResultantCsv(List<OutputCsvDataDto> outputDataList) 
  {
    List<String> files = this.getOutgoingFileName();
    for (String fileName : files) {
        this.outgoingFilepath = 
        this.renameFilePathWithDate(this.outgoingFilepath);
        new File(this.outgoingFilepath.trim()).mkdirs();
        fileName = this.outgoingFilepath + "/" + fileName;
        log.info("Output csv name : " + fileName);
        this.writer.writeToCsv(outputDataList, fileName);
        this.backupFile(fileName, this.fileBackupPath);
        }
 }
```

The files object has 3 records.It Processes the records for the first file in files object.Reads the second object but still have data for the 1st object.How to clear data for the first record before processing to the second record???

Comment: Use `Iterator` to loop over the files List and  `iterator.remove();`

Comment: You can use `Iterator` and it's `.remove()` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Iterator`.
Let's say for example you want to remove the current `String` which is given by the loop:

```
Iterator<String> filesIterator = this.getOutgoingFileName().iterator();
while(filesIterator.hasNext()) {
    String fileName = filesIterator.next();
    //TODO do your stuff
    filesIterator.remove(); //Removes it from the List<String> (getOutgoingFileName())
}
```

Comment: thanks..How can i use iterator when there we are list in a list...like this..                                                                                                for (List<Address> listOfAddress : this.addressLists) {
   for (Address address : listOfAddress) {                                   //some code                                            }}...How can I clear listOfAddress Object after first for loop executes..

Comment: You can do that the same way:  
`Iterator<List<Address>> iterator = this.addressLists.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
 List<Address> listOfAddress = iterator.next();
 Iterator<Address> iterator2 = listOfAddress.iterator();
 while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
  Address address = iterator2.next();
  //some code
  iterator2.remove();
 }
}`